# Extract substring in batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
set line = xxx/yyy/xxx/xxxxxxxx.h:32:#include "../../xxxx/xxxxx.h"
```

if this is the string, how can i extract just xxxxxxxx.h, between / and : in batch script?

i have included the bin path of cygwin to my windows environment variables so it can run grep commands.
Current, this is my script:

```
   @echo off

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set /p search_parameter="Type your search: "

rem run grep seach commmand
grep -nri %search_parameter% --colour --include=*.{c,h} > text.txt

rem filter required lines into new text file
type text.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text2.txt

rem read text file line-by-line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
set "line=%%G"
rem echo line: !line!
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%i"
for %%i in (!line:/= !) do set "line=%%i"
echo line: !line!

)

pause

echo on
```

Currently, this is my output:

```
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
line: line:/
```

The problem is this line:

```
for %%i in (!line:/= !) do set "line=%%i"
```

Comment: Did you want to get [this](https://regex101.com/r/OtUYqa/1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to get the part before the first `:`.
Then use a plain `for` to get the last token of this part (tokenize by replacing `/` with spaces):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "line=xxx/yyy/xxx/xxxxxxxx.h:32:#include "../../xxxx/xxxxx.h""
set line
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ("%line%") do set "line=%%a"
set line
for %%a in (%line:/= %) do set "line=%%a"
set line
```

Output of this code:

```
line=xxx/yyy/xxx/xxxxxxxx.h:32:#include "../../xxxx/xxxxx.h"
line=xxx/yyy/xxx/xxxxxxxx.h
line=xxxxxxxx.h
```

due to the exact format of your string, you can just:

```
set "line=xxx/yyy/xxx/xxxxxxxx.h:32:#include "../../xxxx/xxxxx.h""
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ("%line%") do set "line=%%~nxa"
```

(Thanks, @dbenham). This works because the parser "translates" the "wrong" slash (not valid for a filename) to the "correct" backslash and `%%~nxa` just extracts the "filename and extension" from the "full file name". (`for` treats the string as a filename but doesn't even care, if it's valid)

**Edit**

```
...
rem read text file line-by-line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
  set "line=%%G"
  for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%~nxi" 
  echo line: !line!
)
```

Comment: Assuming the final content never contains a \ character, then you only need the one `FOR /F` by using `set "line=%~nxa"`

Comment: @dbenham Huh? That's unexpected. It ignores the last part because `:` isn't a valid char for filenames? And because it also "corrects" the "wrong (for a valid path)" / to a \? Two exploits in one command? You're in top-form today! `:D`

Comment: Not quite - The `FOR /F "DELIMS=:"` is still responsible for truncating from the `:` onward. The `%~nxa` is responsible for stripping of the leading path through the last `/`. Without the `delims=:` the `:` and beyond would still be preserved by `%~nxa`, even though it is not valid for a name or extension.

Comment: @dbenham: [facepalm] Yes, the `delims` - I completely forgot that... Proves that *I*'m not in top-form today.

Comment: @Stephan may i know what the set line for?

Comment: `set line` is for watching what happens. It only shows the variable `line` and has no influence on the code flow itself. You can safely remove those lines.

Comment: @Stephan hi, i upgraded my scripts, and for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%i" is working, but for %%i in (!line:/= !) do set "line=%%i" is not working

Comment: Did you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`?

Comment: @Stephan yup i have set it, plus i have update my original post to show the current script i am using

Answer (score 0):

```
  @echo off

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set /p search_parameter="Type your search: "

rem run grep seach commmand
grep -nri %search_parameter% --colour --include=*.{c,h} > text.txt

rem filter required lines into new text file
type text.txt | findstr /I "#include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL" > text2.txt

rem read text file line-by-line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (text2.txt) do (
set "line=%%G"
rem echo line: !line!
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("!line!") do set "line=%%~nxi"
echo line: !line!

)

pause

echo on
```